# Build dynamodb stream arn

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb

I don't know if there is a lack in the documentation but I did not see how to build the correct ARN for GetRecords stream items.

Well, previously I have retrieve the description : the result

```
{
  StreamDescription: {
    CreationRequestDateTime: 2017-09-03 13:00:59 +0000 UTC,
    KeySchema: [{
        AttributeName: "uuid",
        KeyType: "HASH"
      }],
    Shards: [{
        SequenceNumberRange: {
          StartingSequenceNumber: "000000000000000000001"
        },
        ShardId: "shardId-00000001504443659977-73044b57"
      }],
    StreamArn: "arn:aws:dynamodb:ddblocal:000000000000:table/sound/stream/2017-09-03T13:00:59.970",
    StreamLabel: "2017-09-03T13:00:59.970",
    StreamStatus: "ENABLED",
    StreamViewType: "NEW_IMAGE",
    TableName: "sound"
  }
}
```

And I have see the example at the end of this page : http://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/APIReference/API_streams_GetRecords.html#API_streams_GetRecords_RequestSyntax

```
POST / HTTP/1.1
x-amzn-RequestId: <RequestID>
x-amzn-crc32: <CRC32>
Content-Type: application/x-amz-json-1.0
Content-Length: <PayloadSizeBytes>     
X-Amz-Date: <Date> 
X-Amz-Target: DynamoDBStreams_20120810.GetRecords

{
    "ShardIterator": "arn:aws:dynamodb:us-west-2:111122223333:table/Forum/stream/2015-05-20T20:51:10.252|1|AAAAAAAAAAEvJp6D+zaQ...  <remaining characters omitted> ..."
}
```

And I try do done this with my description like that :

```
arn:aws:dynamodb:ddblocal:000000000000:table/sound/stream/2017-09-03T13:00:59.970/1/00000001504443659977-73044b57
```

But the response is error 400  Invalid ShardIterator.

Have you some idea for create the correct ARN ?